# Fix reledmac RTL footer indice

Tags: luatex, reledmac

Using the code below I get the result from the image: The numbers are RTL although they should be LTR. I get 01, 11, 21... instead of 10, 11, 12... and I don't know how to switch them around.

I think I could do it with `\renewcommand{\thefootnoteA}` but I cannot figure out the syntax and cannot find any good examples.

I'm building the following tex with: `latexmk -pvc -pdf -e '$pdflatex=q/lualatex %O -interaction=nonstopmode %S/' file.tex`

Any help, documentation or example would be kindly appreciated!

```
%%% document class determines a lot of styling defaults
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}


%%% import needed packages
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{arabluatex} % for arabic linguratures
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[noend,noeledsec,series={A}]{reledmac} % for editions
\usepackage{reledpar}
\usepackage{typearea}
\usepackage{color} % for text colors
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}
\usepackage{selinput}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{luabidi} % for bidirectional text


%%% load fonts
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Amiri} % font


%%% document settings
\AtBeginDocument{\onehalfspace}
\setdefaultlanguage{german} % for arabic text only use: arabic
\def\@fnpos{critical-familiar}
\fnpos{critical-familiar}
\mpfnpos{critical-familiar}
\parindent 0pt
\newlength\myboxwidth
\setlength{\myboxwidth}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep}
%%% \setRTLmain % set main direction to right to left


%%% configure column widths
\setlength{\Lcolwidth}{0.35\textwidth}
\setlength{\Rcolwidth}{0.6\textwidth}


%%% configure line numeration
\linenummargin{right} % print line numbers right (alternative is: left)


%%% configure lemmas to be rtl
\Xwraplemma{\RL} % set lemmas to rtl
\Xlemmaseparator{:} % set lemma seperatore


%%% configure footers to go right to left
\Xarrangement{paragraph} % format footer as paragraph (all in one line)
\Xbhookgroup[A]{\pardir TRT\textdir TRT}
\Xwrapcontent[A]{\txarb}

%%% custom commands
\makeatletter % temporarliy disable @ letter
\newcommand{\ta}{\txarb} %\ar in den Editionsfussnoten nötig
\newcommand{\morenoexpands}{\let\textcolor\@secondoftwo}
\newcommand{\dmg}[1]{{\emph{#1}}} %  DMG Transliteration und gleichzeitig Kursivsetzung
\makeatother % reenable @ letter

\begin{document}

%%% part 1
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\setline{9}
\begin{arab}
    \edtext{\ta{منفعة}}{\Afootnote{\ta{ب، م: جلاء} \textbf{ب، م}}} بسبب ما فيه\\
    \edtext{\ta{منفعة}}{\Afootnote{\ta{ب، م: جلاء} \textbf{ب، م}}} بسبب ما فيه\\
    \edtext{\ta{منفعة}}{\Afootnote{\ta{ب، م: جلاء} \textbf{ب، م}}} بسبب ما فيه\\
    \edtext{\ta{منفعة}}{\Afootnote{\ta{ب، م: جلاء} \textbf{ب، م}}} بسبب ما فيه\\
    \edtext{\ta{منفعة}}{\Afootnote{\ta{ب، م: جلاء} \textbf{ب، م}}} بسبب ما فيه\\
    \edtext{\ta{منفعة}}{\Afootnote{\ta{ب، م: جلاء} \textbf{ب، م}}} بسبب ما فيه\\
    \edtext{\ta{منفعة}}{\Afootnote{\ta{ب، م: جلاء} \textbf{ب، م}}} بسبب ما فيه\\
\end{arab}
\pend
\endnumbering

\end{document}
```

[image: footer]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `\thefootnoteA` is for familiar footnotes (that is with a marker in text), so not for you.
2. What you need is to have linenumber in LR mode (I get time to point this thing)
3. Unfortunatly, there is no, actually, `\Xwrapnumber` hook (but you may open an issue on github)
4. What you could do is to patch `\linenumrep` to wrap its content in  `LR` macro. So

```
\pretocmd{\linenumrep}{\LR\bgroup}{}{}
\apptocmd{\linenumrep}{\egroup}{}{}
```

And consequently

```
%%% document class determines a lot of styling defaults
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}


%%% import needed packages
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{arabluatex} % for arabic linguratures
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[noend,noeledsec,series={A}]{reledmac} % for editions
\usepackage{reledpar}
\usepackage{typearea}
\usepackage{color} % for text colors
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}
\usepackage{selinput}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{luabidi} % for bidirectional text


%%% load fonts
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Amiri} % font


%%% document settings
\AtBeginDocument{\onehalfspace}
\setdefaultlanguage{german} % for arabic text only use: arabic
\def\@fnpos{critical-familiar}
\fnpos{critical-familiar}
\mpfnpos{critical-familiar}
\parindent 0pt
\newlength\myboxwidth
\setlength{\myboxwidth}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep}
%%% \setRTLmain % set main direction to right to left


%%% configure column widths
\setlength{\Lcolwidth}{0.35\textwidth}
\setlength{\Rcolwidth}{0.6\textwidth}


%%% configure line numeration
\linenummargin{right} % print line numbers right (alternative is: left)


%%% configure lemmas to be rtl
\Xwraplemma{\RL} % set lemmas to rtl
\Xlemmaseparator{:} % set lemma seperatore

%%% Line number always in LTR !
\pretocmd{\linenumrep}{\LR\bgroup}{}{}
\apptocmd{\linenumrep}{\egroup}{}{}


%%% configure footers to go right to left
\Xarrangement{paragraph} % format footer as paragraph (all in one line)
\Xbhookgroup[A]{\pardir TRT\textdir TRT}
\Xwrapcontent[A]{\txarb}

%%% custom commands
\makeatletter % temporarliy disable @ letter
\newcommand{\ta}{\txarb} %\ar in den Editionsfussnoten nötig
\newcommand{\morenoexpands}{\let\textcolor\@secondoftwo}
\newcommand{\dmg}[1]{{\emph{#1}}} %  DMG Transliteration und gleichzeitig Kursivsetzung
\makeatother % reenable @ letter

\begin{document}

%%% part 1
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\setline{9}
\begin{arab}
    \edtext{\ta{منفعة}}{\Afootnote{\ta{ب، م: جلاء} \textbf{ب، م}}} بسبب ما فيه\\
    \edtext{\ta{منفعة}}{\Afootnote{\ta{ب، م: جلاء} \textbf{ب، م}}} بسبب ما فيه\\
    \edtext{\ta{منفعة}}{\Afootnote{\ta{ب، م: جلاء} \textbf{ب، م}}} بسبب ما فيه\\
    \edtext{\ta{منفعة}}{\Afootnote{\ta{ب، م: جلاء} \textbf{ب، م}}} بسبب ما فيه\\
    \edtext{\ta{منفعة}}{\Afootnote{\ta{ب، م: جلاء} \textbf{ب، م}}} بسبب ما فيه\\
    \edtext{\ta{منفعة}}{\Afootnote{\ta{ب، م: جلاء} \textbf{ب، م}}} بسبب ما فيه\\
    \edtext{\ta{منفعة}}{\Afootnote{\ta{ب، م: جلاء} \textbf{ب، م}}} بسبب ما فيه\\
\end{arab}
\pend
\endnumbering

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so very much. I would never have found out how to fix it like that. I tried to convince my wife (islamic studies) to use latex, but now struggle to help her set it up properly. I wish you well and hope you continue your awesome work!